# Which is the right preposition to use: in/on/at the campus residences?

Tags: prepositions

There are two examples for which I am looking for the right preposition:

> 1. Students who live in/on/at the campus residences.
> 2. Poor internet connection in/on/at the campus residences.

I know we say "to live on campus". But, I can not find any information for this specific examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both examples either *in* or *at* would work but *on* is, as you suspected, wrong. I would prefer *in* for the first example

> Students who live in the campus residences

although it is common to speak of living at a particular address, the UK PM lives at 10 Downing Street.

For the second example I cannot see any reason to prefer one over the other.